# Accessing a datatable via a string variable

Tags: variables, datatable

This is probably one of those that is so simple I can't see it. I have a string variable called Market. The variable is user chosen and is the exact same name as one of many tables in my dataset. Basically I am having the user choose which table they want in a combobox, then I want to use that variable to access the table. So if the user picks "Market1" then I want to open the table named Market1.

I am simplifying here, but need to know how to open:

```
For ds.<variable here>.rows.count - 1
    'perform steps
Next
```

How do I inject the variable correctly? Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataset has Tables property, which accepts table name as a parameter. So in your case if string variable `Market` holds table name, you can access the table by referring to `ds.Tables(Market)`

Comment: I knew it was easy. Thanks much!